# Metro app : gridview with auto switch item content

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, gridview, microsoft-metro

I want to create a grouped gridview of images : no problem.

Now i would assign many image per gridview item, with an auto switch image after delay. (like app tiles notification)

I can imagine a tricky way with flipview and scheduled task but is there a clean and smooth way to do this?

may be a tutorial link?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use tile control as a DataTemplate for gridview item. There are some commercial controls, and you can find free implementation with source code, something like Calisto: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/05/31/introducing-callisto-a-xaml-toolkit-for-metro-apps.aspx